# Using Ping constantly to verify connection and display feedback on python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ping

I am trying to make a small app with python tkinter.
in which i will need a ping command to constantly check for connection to a certain device example '192.168.1.21' and tells me if the device is connected or not real time.
Nota: i am using ping3
this is my program:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
label_1 = Label(root, text = "Not connected")
label_1.pack()




def testing(label):
    if ping('192.168.1.21', timeout=0.5) != None: #To test the connection 1 time
        label.config(text = "Connected")
    else:
        label.config(text = "Not Connected")

    label.after(500, lambda : testing(label_1))

def popup(): #A popup that does the same thing
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("150x150")
    label_2 = Label(top, text = "Not connected")
    label_2.pack()
    label_2.after(500, lambda : testing(label_2))
    top.mainloop()

btn = Button(root, text = "Popup", command=popup)
btn.pack()

testing(label_1)

root.mainloop()
```

How can i make it not freeze and keep testing while letting the rest of the program run smoothly.
Thank you and sorry if I made mistakes in the code, i am still new to python in generale.

Comment: you need to post your imports together with your code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using threading. This allows the tkinter mainloop and the pinging to happen concurrently which means the GUI doesn't freeze.

```
import threading, time, sys

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
label_1 = Label(root, text = "Not connected")
label_1.pack()


current_value = None
continue_thread = True

def doPing():
    global current_value, continue_thread
    while continue_thread:
        current_value = ping('192.168.1.21', timeout=0.5)
        time.sleep(0.5) # 500ms delay before pinging again
    sys.exit() # Stop thread when window is closed


def testing(label):
    global current_value
    if current_value != None: #To test the connection 1 time
        label.config(text = "Connected")
    else:
        label.config(text = "Not Connected")

    label.after(500, lambda : testing(label))

def popup(): #A popup that does the same thing
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("150x150")
    label_2 = Label(top, text = "Not connected")
    label_2.pack()
    label_2.after(500, lambda : testing(label_2))
    top.mainloop()

btn = Button(root, text = "Popup", command=popup)
btn.pack()

ping_thread = threading.Thread(target = doPing)
ping_thread.start()
testing(label_1)

root.mainloop()
continue_thread = False # end thread after window is closed
```

The program now uses a thread, `ping_thread`, which runs `doPing`. `doPing` calls `ping`, updates `current_value` and then waits 500ms before calling itself again. Then in the main thread `testing` updates the label every 500ms using the value of `current_value`. When the window is closed and `root.mainloop` has finished `continue_thread` is set to false so then `sys.exit` is called, stopping the thread.

There are 2 global variables `current_value` and `continue_thread`. The first allows you to access the return value of `ping` in `testing` and the second allows the main thread to tell the ping thread to stop when the Tkinter window is closed. Global variables are not good programming practice and I'd advise using classes instead. I've used them here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: It is better to use while loop instead of recursion inside `doPing()` because `recursion limit` will be reached after it is running for a long period.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll edit it

Comment: Will it work when you have the functions and pages in seperate files and import them in a main.py file and the continue_thread, current_value are globale in main.py ?

Comment: You would have to import `continue_thread` and `current_value` in the other files